# android 10 `SSL handshake time out` since 1 September

Tags: android, ssl, timeout, okhttp, handshake

I am an android programmer.
I support and develop a trading app.
It works with sever API by ssl tls 1.2 and uses lib retrofit2(okhttp)

Since 1 September I am seeing jumps of network failure errors with message `SSL handshake time out`.
It happens only android 10 and dependeтs of mobile provider.
This is most noticeable on the 'Beeline' (is is second popular Russian mobile provider)

We didn't change server side and didn't publish any new version of app.
Any ideas what happen?

[daily errors, android 10, grouped by provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZczQ.png) 
[hourly errors, android 10, only Beeline provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQZQB.png)